# limiting align-current in LaTeX-mode

Tags: emacs, auctex, elisp

When working on a LaTeX document in Emacs `align-current` aligns `&` and `\\`, but does so for entire sections at a time. Anyone have any idea as to how one limits its range (in a new macro) to say the current environment?

I seldom need to do an align of anythis other than a matrix or a table.

My attempts to build something on top of `align-regexp` have not been successful.

Ideas?

Edit:

Given the following test data `M-X align-current` will normally align the `&`'s and `\\`'s, but on a sectional basis. I'd like them to work only on the current environment.

```
\begin{tabular}{xxx}
  a & bbbb & sdssd & \\
ccsssssss & jj& bb
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{xxx}
      a & bbbb & sdssd & \\
cc & jj& bb
\end{tabular}
```

If I run it in this example, it aligned them in both tabulars at the same time.

Comment: I guess that this is *not* connected to LaTeX, otherwise you'd have posted it directly here. Probably you should make clearer what the question is about.

Comment: @egreg: the most likely is that it has to do with emacs/AucTeX. Daleif, please confirm.

Comment: hmm, I thought I did tag it, added `emacs`, `auctex`, `elisp`, it is about writing macros in Emacs.

Comment: who can migrate it to somewhere more suitable, this is not a `TeX` question

Comment: I'm not sure there is a more suitable place. Emacs questions fit equally well/poorly everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align-current` usually does the right thing for me. It only aligned multiple sections when there was no space before or after the `\section` macro. You can force align to stay within the current section with the following addition to your .emacs:

```lisp
(defun align-section ()
  "Apply align to the current section only."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (LaTeX-mark-section)
    (align (point) (mark))))

(defun align-environment ()
  "Apply align to the current environment only."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (LaTeX-mark-environment)
    (align (point) (mark))))
```

Edit: I misunderstood the scope. The second function will limit the alignment to the current environment, not the whole section.

Note that this doesn't change `align-current`, but provides a new function to do what you want. Call it with `M-x align-environment`.

Comment: Not quite what is wanted, I want it to do this on an environment basis, buy then `(LaTeX-mark-environment)` should do the trick, I'll do some testing

Comment: That does not do the same thing as `align-current`, see update

Comment: Second one does not do anything for me. Did you test it under `latex-mode` and preferably with `auctex` installed?

Comment: Yes, I just rechecked, copy and paste from my answer to emacs, and it aligns one but not both of the tables in your example. Auctex version 11.86, Emacs 24.1.50.2.

Comment: To clarify, the code above doesn't change the way `align-current` behaves. It provides `align-environment` as an alternative. So after running the code, you should use `M-x align-environment` instead of `M-x align-current`.

Comment: I know, I'm running `Emacs 22` and `auctex 11.85`, and it does not seem to work for me. The `&`'s are never aligned. It alignes some of the text, but not the `&`'s

Comment: That is four-year-old software. A lot has happened in emacs and auctex - I recommend upgrading to the latest release. The align functions in particular are new i think.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is just one issue: the cursor is moved back to the starting point of the environment. Is it possible to restore the position of the cursor (of course taking into account the added indentation)?

Comment: @tobiasBora there was a typo, try the new version

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!